# Pyspark: Delta table as stream source, How to do it?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am facing issue in readStream on delta table.

What is expected, reference from following link
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-streaming.html#delta-table-as-a-stream-source
Ex:

```
spark.readStream.format("delta").table("events")  -- As expected, should work fine
```

Issue, I have tried the same in the following way:

```
df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("deltatable")  -- Saved the Dataframe as a delta table

spark.readStream.format("delta").table("deltatable") -- Called readStream
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'DataStreamReader' object has no attribute 'table'
```

Note:
I am running it in localhost, using pycharm IDE,
Installed latest version of pyspark, spark version = 2.4.5, Scala version 2.11.12

Comment: To confirm, using Open Source Delta Lake or databricks-connect to a Databricks cluster?
What version of the Delta Lake jar are you using (if running on your laptop/desktop)?

Comment: Your example works in a Databricks notebook

Comment: I am using open source Delta lake, spark.jars.packages="io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1". However, as you mentioned this code is working fine in Databricks Notebook. May I know the reason?

Comment: I don't know really know because your 1st line and 3rd line look identical. Unless there is some kind of syntax error in-between, I don't know. Do note... almost all of the Delta examples use directory paths rather than table names. I spend the whole day working in the Managed Delta code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try now with [Delta Lake 0.7.0 release](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v0.7.0) which provides support for registering your tables with the Hive metastore. As mentioned in a comment, most of the Delta Lake examples used a folder path, because metastore support wasn't integrated before this.

Also note, it's best for the Open Source version of Delta Lake to follow the docs at https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The `DataStreamReader.table` and `DataStreamWriter.table` methods are not in Apache Spark yet. Currently you need to use Databricks Notebook in order to call them.

Comment: any idea on when this will be available ?

Comment: Probably Apache Spark 3.1.0, by the end of the year.